# Guestbook tutorial and redis cannot find master

Tags: kubernetes

I am working on the [gcloud tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook).

The redis slave always returns in the log

6:S 18 Sep 09:06:24.808 * Connecting to MASTER redis-master:6379
6:S 18 Sep 09:06:24.817 # Unable to connect to MASTER: No such file or directory
6:S 18 Sep 09:06:25.819 * Connecting to MASTER redis-master:6379
6:S 18 Sep 09:06:25.824 # Unable to connect to MASTER: No such file or directory

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Would someone have an idea or a pathway I can investigate?

Comment: After what step in that tutorial the issue appears?

Comment: Thank you VKR, I did a mistake typing something probably. I redid everything today and this is working :/